# Qn related to incenter

Tags: geometry

Angle bisectors of  traingle $ABC$  meet its circum-circle ( after passing through in-center) at opposite points  $P, Q$, and $R$ respectively on the circumcircle.

Find $\angle RQP.$

Is there any way of getting the answer through its in-center properties?

Ans = $90-\frac{B}{2}$

Comment: By cyclic triangle do you mean the circumcircle? Are points $P,Q,R $ located on the circumcircle?

Comment: @narasimham  yes !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\angle PQR=\angle PQB+\angle RQB=\angle PAB+\angle RCB=\frac{1}{2}A+\frac{1}{2}C=\frac{1}{2}(A+C)=\frac{1}{2}(\pi-B).$$

Comment: Is there any way to find it using incenter properties ??

Comment: The equalities $\angle PAB=\frac{1}{2}A$, $RCB=\frac{1}{2}C$ use incenter property.

Comment: How anglePAB = 1/2 angle A ??

Comment: The incenter of an triangle $ABC$ is the intersection of angular bisectors of $A,B,C$,

Comment: Yes i know that but how does it makes anglePAB = 1/2A

Comment: What is the definition of angular bisector?

Comment: Angular bisector divide the angle in equal halves

Comment: $PAB=PAC$, $PAB+PAC=A$. What conclusion could you derive about the value of angles $PAB$ and $PAC$?

Comment: Sorry i made wrong diagram & was struggling with it. I agree with your point & then you used PAB = PQB (same arc have equal angles)

Answer (score 0):

Recall that inscribed angles over the same arc are equal, as well as that the sum of the angles of a triangle equals $180^o$. Edit your progress.